# How do I form submit input data to display in another view in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am fairly new to laravel I am attempting to pass input data from a form into another view, so far I am able to `print_r` the data but i want it to show up in another view I have. Here is my code

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/','OneWayController@OneWayFormData');
Route::get('formsubmit','OneWayController@fetch');

Route::post('/oneWayTrips', 'OneWayController@formSubmit');
```

the form in `index.blade.php` [Here is the view rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWIXO.png)

```
<form action="{{url('oneWayTrips')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <select name="DepartureAirline" id="airline" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                @foreach ($airlines as $airline)
                <option value="{{$airline->name}}">{{$airline->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <select name="ArrivalAirline" id="airline" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                @foreach ($airlines as $airline)
                <option value="{{$airline->name}}">{{$airline->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="date" name="departureTime" class="form-control form-control-lg" >
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`oneWayTrips.blade.php` - This is where I want to display the input data so for example it should say something like "Departing Airline: Air Canada"

```
<p>Departing Airline: DEPARTINGAIRLINE</p> 
<p>Arrival Airline: ARRIVALAIRLINE</p> 
<p>Departure Date: DEPARTING DATE</
```

p>

`OneWayController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OneWayController extends Controller {
    public function OneWayFormData(){
        $airlines = DB::select('select * from airlines');
        return view('index',['airlines'=>$airlines]);
    }
    public function formSubmit(Request $req){


        print_r($req->input('arrivalAirline'));
        print_r($req->input('departureAirline'));
        print_r($req->input('departureDate'));

        return view('oneWayTrips', compact('req'));

    }

}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views might help

Comment: you can sent them with session

Comment: Thanks for the suggesitons i got a bit closer but still a little confused. So i am now able to display the form data in the controller but I have still not figured out how to make it display in the oneWayTrips.blade.php view https://i.imgur.com/Z92oS4N.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should try in `OneWayController`**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OneWayController extends Controller {
    public function OneWayFormData(){
        $airlines = DB::select('select * from airlines');
        return view('index',['airlines'=>$airlines]);
    }
    public function formSubmit(Request $request){

        $input = Input::all();
        $form_data = array();
        $form_data['arrivalAirline'] = $input['arrivalAirline'];
        $form_data['departureAirline'] = $input['departureAirline'];
        $form_data['departureDate'] = $input['departureDate'];

        return view('oneWayTrips', compact('form_data'));
    }

}
```

**In Blade**

```
<p>Departing Airline: {{$form_data->departureAirline}}</p> 
<p>Arrival Airline: {{$form_data->arrivalAirline}}</p> 
<p>Departure Date: {{$form_data->departureDate}}</p>
```

*OR*

```
<p>Departing Airline: {{$form_data['departureAirline']}}</p> 
<p>Arrival Airline: {{$form_data['arrivalAirline']}}</p> 
<p>Departure Date: {{$form_data['departureDate']}}</p>
```

Comment: your solution really put me on the right track and iw as able to figure it out thank you! the olny difference is instead of  $input = Input::all(); I used $input = $request->all();